Как написать калькулятор в одном input'е?
Всем здравствуйте!
У меня такая идея, но пока не могу дойти до реализации. Хочу сделать калькулятор в одной вводной строчке, пример на скриншоте.

Я начал что-то писать, но столкнулся с тем, что я просто не понимаю как мне в одной строке обработать знаки и цифры. Сначала показалось просто, раскидать по массивам (отсеять цифры от знаков) но и тут я не могу завершить идею. Вот пример, как это выглядит (2 + 2) с этим я быстро решил все, но сложность в том, если я вдруг захочу не 2 числа сложить, а сложный пример, (2 + 2 * 5 / 2)
Вот что пока есть:


let btn = document.getElementById('button');
let inpt = document.getElementById('input');
let res = document.getElementById('result');

function math(e) {

  let arr = String(e).split(' ');

  arr.forEach((element, index) => {

    if (element == '-' || element == '+' || element == '/' || element == '*') {

      //res.innerHTML += element + ' (' + index + ') ';

      const arrSum = [element];
    } else {

      const arrNumber = [element];
      //res.innerHTML += element + ' (' + index + ') ';
    };


    //res.innerHTML += " (" + element + " | " + index + ") ";
  });


  //res.innerHTML = a;

};

btn.onclick = function() {

  if (inpt.value !== '') {

    //const i = String(inpt.value).split(' ');
    math(inpt.value);


  } else {

    res.innerHTML = 'Поле не может быть пустым';
  }
};



Прошу помощи у знающих.

Вот тебе статейка на эту тему https://habr.com/ru/articles/596925/

На самом деле это хорошая алгоритмическая задача, которую, лично я бы, советовал попробовать решить самостоятельно.
Решения
1) eval
Очень плохой вариант, в браузерах лучше не использовать, но JS позволяет выполнять код внутри строки используя eval:
eval('2+2*(74/(32+5))') // Выведет 6

О проблемах eval вы можете почитать например здесь
Для хитрецов, знающих, что eval нельзя использовать напрямую, есть аналог через new Function:
const expression = '2+2*(74/(32+5))'
const res = (new Function(`return ${expression}`))() // Вернет 6

2) Алгоритм
"Правильное" алгоритмическое решение может выглядеть например вот так:
function evaluateExpression(expression) {
    function getPriority(operator) {
        // Приоритет операции
        switch (operator) {
            case '+':
            case '-':
                return 1;
            case '*':
            case '/':
                return 2;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
    function applyOperation(operands, operator) {
        //Выполнение одной простой операции
        const b = operands.pop();
        const a = operands.pop();
        switch (operator) {
            case '+':
                operands.push(a + b);
                break;
            case '-':
                operands.push(a - b);
                break;
            case '*':
                operands.push(a * b);
                break;
            case '/':
                operands.push(a / b);
                break;
        }
        //Раскомментируйте, чтобы видеть порядок выполнения
        //console.log(`Выполнение ${a} ${operator} ${b} = ${operands[operands.length-1]}`)
    }
    const operators = [];
    const operands = [];
    let i = 0;

    while (i < expression.length) {
        const char = expression[i];
        //Пропуск пробелов
        if (char === ' ') {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        //Посимвольный сбор числа
        if (char >= '0' && char <= '9') {
            let buffer = '';
            while (i < expression.length && (expression[i] >= '0' && expression[i] <= '9' || expression[i] === '.')) {
                buffer += expression[i++];
            }
            operands.push(parseFloat(buffer));
            continue;
        }

        //Обработка скобок
        if (char === '(') {
            operators.push(char);
        } else if (char === ')') {
            while (operators.length && operators[operators.length - 1] !== '(') {
                applyOperation(operands, operators.pop());
            }
            operators.pop();
        } else if ("+-*/".includes(char)) {
            while (operators.length && getPriority(operators[operators.length - 1]) >= getPriority(char)) {
                applyOperation(operands, operators.pop());
            }
            operators.push(char);
        }
        i++;
    }
    //Выполнение оставшихся операций
    while (operators.length) {
        applyOperation(operands, operators.pop());
    }
    return operands[0];
}

const expression = "2+2*(74/(32+5))";
console.log(evaluateExpression(expression)); // Вывод: 6


Примерная идея такая:

Проходимся по строке
Собираем операнды (числа) в стэк чисел, а операторы (знаки) в массив операторов
Выполняем операции

Разберем посимвольно на примере 2+2*(74/(32+5)):
operators = []
operands = []


Встретили 2 - добавили в стек чисел

operators = []
operands = [2]


Встретили +, добавили к операторам

operators = ['+']
operands = [2]


Встретили 2, добавили к операндам:

operators = ['+']
operands = [2, 2]


Встретили *, т.к. его приоритет выше предыдущего (+), добавляем его к операторам.

operators = ['+', '*']
operands = [2, 2]


Встретили скобку (, добавили к операторам:

operators = ['+', '*', '(']
operands = [2, 2]


Увидели 7, а после увидели 4, вместе получили 74, добавили к операндам:

operators = ['+', '*', '(']
operands = [2, 2, 74]


Увидели /, его оператор выше, чем у скобки (у скобки 0), значит добавляем его к операторам

operators = ['+', '*', '(', '/']
operands = [2, 2, 74]


Увидели скобку (, добавляем ее к операторам:

operators = ['+', '*', '(', '/', '(']
operands = [2, 2, 74]


Увидели 3, далее 2, получили 32, добавили к операндам

operators = ['+', '*', '(', '/', '(']
operands = [2, 2, 74, 32]


Увидели +, добавили к операторам

operators = ['+', '*', '(', '/', '(', '+']
operands = [2, 2, 74, 32]


Увидели 5, добавили к операндам:

operators = ['+', '*', '(', '/', '(', '+']
operands = [2, 2, 74, 32, 5]


Увидели закрывающую скобку, выполнили операции до открывающей скобки:

operators = ['+', '*', '(', '/', '(', '+']
operands = [2, 2, 74, 32, 5]
//Достали последние 2 числа из `operands`:
operands = [2, 2, 74]; a = 32, b = 5;

// Достали последний оператор из `operators`
operators = ['+', '*', '(', '/', '(']; operator = '+'
//32, 5, Оператор `+`, вычислили, получили 32+5 = 37.
// Добавили 37 в конец оставшихся операндов, удалили открывающую скобку
operators = ['+', '*', '(', '/']
operands = [2, 2, 74, 37]


Увидели еще одну скобку, выполнили по аналогии:

operators = ['+', '*', '(', '/']
operands = [2, 2, 74, 37]
//Достали последние 2 числа из `operands`:
operands = [2, 2]; a = 74, b = 37;

// Достали последний оператор из `operators`
operators = ['+', '*', '(']; operator = '/'
//74, 37, Оператор `/`, вычислили, получили 74/37 = 2.
// Добавили 2 в конец оставшихся операндов, удалили открывающую скобку
operators = ['+', '*']
operands = [2, 2, 2]


Дошли до конца строки, выполнили оставшиеся операции:

operators = ['+', '*']
operands = [2, 2, 2]
//Достали последние 2 числа из `operands`:
operands = [2]; a = 2, b = 2'

// Достали последний оператор из `operators`
operators = ['+']; operator = '*'
//2, 2, Оператор `*`, вычислили, получили 2*2 = 4.
// Добавили 4 в конец оставшихся операндов
operators = ['+']
operands = [2, 4]

//Достали последние 2 числа из `operands`:
operands = []; a = 2; b = 4;
// Достали последний оператор из `operators`
operators = []; operator = '+'
//2, 4, Оператор `+`, вычислили, получили 2+4 = 6.
// Добавили 6 в конец оставшихся операндов


В массиве операторов ничего не осталось, значит последнее число в операндах наш ответ.

operators = []
operands = [6]

Вернули 6 в качестве ответа.
Надеюсь, алгоритм понятен.
Если бы мы увидели операции в другом порядке, например:
3*6+4
То было бы так:
operators = []
operands = []


Добавили 3:

operators = []
operands = [3]


добавили *:

operators = ['*']
operands = [3]


Добавили 6:

operators = ['*']
operands = [3, 6]


Встретили +. Т.к. у + оператора, приоритет ниже, чем у *, выполняем те операции, которые есть перед +, пока их приоритет не станет ниже (ниже + только скобка):

operators = ['*']
operands = [3, 6]

//Достали последние 2 числа из `operands`:
operands = []; a = 3, b = 6'

// Достали последний оператор из `operators`
operators = []; operator = '*'
// 3, 6, Оператор `*`, вычислили, получили 3*6 = 18.
// Добавили 18 в конец оставшихся операндов

operands = [18]
operators = [];


Встретили +, добавили в конец операторов:

operands = [18]
operators = ['+'];


Встретили 4, добавили к операндам:

operands = [18, 4]
operators = ['+'];


Дошли до конца строки, выполняем все что осталось:

//Достали последние 2 числа из `operands`:
operands = []; a = 18, b = 4'

// Достали последний оператор из `operators`
operators = []; operator = '+'
// 18, 4, Оператор `+`, вычислили, получили 18+4 = 22.
// Добавили 2 в конец оставшихся операндов
operands = [22];
operators = [];


В массиве операторов ничего не осталось, значит последнее число в операндах наш ответ.

operators = []
operands = [22]

Вернули ответ 22.

Спасибо что расписали! Для меня очень хорошо раскрыли данный момент! Благодарю.

Делается следующим образом. Ищем готовый код на python, заливаем в codeconvert.ai. Генераторы в filter, reduce, map иногда преобразует неверно, но, так как тут их нет, можно считать повезло

Звучит как курсовая работа первого курса университета...

const M_PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
const F_G = 9.81;
const H_LEET = 1337;

const MAX_EXPR_LEN = 255;
const MAX_TOKEN_LEN = 80;

const CALC_END = -1;
const CALC_L_BRACKET = -2;
const CALC_R_BRACKET = -3;
const CALC_NUMBER = -4;

const OP_PLUS = 0;
const OP_MINUS = 1;
const OP_MULTIPLY = 2;
const OP_DIVIDE = 3;
const OP_PERCENT = 4;
const OP_POWER = 5;
const OP_UMINUS = 6;

const OP_SIN = 7;
const OP_COS = 8;
const OP_TG = 9;
const OP_CTG = 10;
const OP_ARCSIN = 11;
const OP_ARCCOS = 12;
const OP_ARCTG = 13;
const OP_ARCCTG = 14;
const OP_SH = 15;
const OP_CH = 16;
const OP_TH = 17;
const OP_CTH = 18;
const OP_EXP = 19;
const OP_LG = 20;
const OP_LN = 21;
const OP_SQRT = 22;
const OP_IN = 23;
const CALC_PI = 24;
const CALC_G = 25;
const CALC_LEET = 26;

const TERMINATOR = "\x00";

function strlen(list1) {
  let i = 0;
  while (list1[i] !== TERMINATOR) {
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}

function strcmp(list1, list2) {
  const total = Math.min(list1.length, list2.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    if (i > list1.length - 1) return false;
    if (i > list2.length - 1) return false;
    if (list1[i] !== list2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function atof(text) {
  const str = text.slice(0, strlen(text)).join("");
  const integer = parseInt(str);
  const double = parseFloat(str);
  return integer === double ? integer : double;
}

class TCALCNode {
  constructor(_value = 0, _left = null, _right = null) {
    this.value = _value;
    this.left = _left;
    this.right = _right;
  }
}

class TCALC {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
    this.expr = Array(MAX_EXPR_LEN).fill(TERMINATOR);
    this.curToken = Array(MAX_TOKEN_LEN).fill(TERMINATOR);
    this.typToken = 0;
    this.pos = 0;
    this.result = 0;
  }

  static IsDelim(self) {
    for (const char of "+-*/%^()[]") {
      if (self.expr[self.pos] === char) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  static IsLetter(self) {
    const char = self.expr[self.pos];
    return (char >= "a" && char <= "z") || (char >= "A" && char <= "Z");
  }

  static IsDigit(self) {
    const char = self.expr[self.pos];
    return char >= "0" && char <= "9";
  }

  static IsPoint(self) {
    return self.expr[self.pos] === ".";
  }

  GetToken() {
    this.curToken[0] = TERMINATOR;
    while (this.expr[this.pos] === " ") {
      this.pos++;
    }
    if (this.expr[this.pos] === TERMINATOR) {
      this.curToken[0] = TERMINATOR;
      this.typToken = CALC_END;
      return true;
    } else if (TCALC.IsDelim(this)) {
      this.curToken[0] = this.expr[this.pos];
      this.pos++;
      this.curToken[1] = TERMINATOR;
      const tmp = this.curToken.slice(0, strlen(this.curToken)).join("");
      switch (tmp) {
        case "+":
          this.typToken = OP_PLUS;
          break;
        case "-":
          this.typToken = OP_MINUS;
          break;
        case "*":
          this.typToken = OP_MULTIPLY;
          break;
        case "/":
          this.typToken = OP_DIVIDE;
          break;
        case "%":
          this.typToken = OP_PERCENT;
          break;
        case "[":
        case "(":
          this.typToken = CALC_L_BRACKET;
          break;
        case "]":
        case ")":
          this.typToken = CALC_R_BRACKET;
          break;
      }
      return true;
    } else if (TCALC.IsLetter(this)) {
      let i = 0;
      while (TCALC.IsLetter(this)) {
        this.curToken[i] = this.expr[this.pos];
        this.pos++;
        i++;
      }
      this.curToken[i] = TERMINATOR;
      const len = strlen(this.curToken);
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (this.curToken[i] >= "A" && this.curToken[i] <= "Z") {
          this.curToken[i] = String.fromCharCode(
            this.curToken[i].charCodeAt(0) +
              "a".charCodeAt(0) -
              "A".charCodeAt(0),
          );
        }
      }
      if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "leet".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = CALC_LEET;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "g".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = CALC_G;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "pi".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = CALC_PI;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "sin".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_SIN;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "cos".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_COS;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "tg".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_TG;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "ctg".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_CTG;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "arcsin".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_ARCSIN;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "arccos".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_ARCCOS;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "sh".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_SH;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "ch".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_CH;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "th".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_TH;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "cth".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_CTH;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "exp".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_EXP;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "lg".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_LG;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "ln".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_LN;
      } else if (!strcmp(this.curToken, "sqrt".split(""))) {
        this.typToken = OP_SQRT;
      } else {
        this.SendError(0);
      }
    } else if (TCALC.IsDigit(this) || TCALC.IsPoint(this)) {
      let i = 0;
      while (TCALC.IsDigit(this)) {
        this.curToken[i] = this.expr[this.pos];
        this.pos++;
        i++;
      }
      if (TCALC.IsPoint(this)) {
        this.curToken[i] = this.expr[this.pos];
        this.pos++;
        i++;
        while (TCALC.IsDigit(this)) {
          this.curToken[i] = this.expr[this.pos];
          this.pos++;
          i++;
        }
      }
      this.curToken[i] = TERMINATOR;
      this.typToken = CALC_NUMBER;
      return true;
    } else {
      this.curToken[0] = this.expr[this.pos];
      this.pos++;
      this.curToken[1] = TERMINATOR;
      this.SendError(1);
    }
    return false;
  }

  CreateNode(_value, _left, _right) {
    return new TCALCNode(_value, _left, _right);
  }

  Expr() {
    let temp = this.Expr1();
    while (true) {
      if (this.typToken === OP_PLUS) {
        this.GetToken();
        temp = this.CreateNode(OP_PLUS, temp, this.Expr1());
      } else if (this.typToken === OP_MINUS) {
        this.GetToken();
        temp = this.CreateNode(OP_MINUS, temp, this.Expr1());
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }

  Expr1() {
    let temp = this.Expr2();
    while (true) {
      if (this.typToken === OP_MULTIPLY) {
        this.GetToken();
        temp = this.CreateNode(OP_MULTIPLY, temp, this.Expr2());
      } else if (this.typToken === OP_DIVIDE) {
        this.GetToken();
        temp = this.CreateNode(OP_DIVIDE, temp, this.Expr2());
      } else if (this.typToken === OP_PERCENT) {
        this.GetToken();
        temp = this.CreateNode(OP_PERCENT, temp, this.Expr2());
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }

  Expr2() {
    let temp = null;
    if (this.typToken === OP_PLUS) {
      this.GetToken();
      temp = this.Expr3();
    } else if (this.typToken === OP_MINUS) {
      this.GetToken();
      temp = this.CreateNode(OP_UMINUS, this.Expr3(), null);
    } else {
      temp = this.Expr3();
    }
    return temp;
  }

  Expr3() {
    let temp = null;
    if (this.typToken >= OP_SIN && this.typToken <= OP_SQRT + 1) {
      temp = this.CreateNode(OP_SIN - OP_SIN + this.typToken, null, null);
      this.GetToken();
      if (this.typToken !== CALC_L_BRACKET) {
        this.SendError(4);
      }
      this.GetToken();
      temp.left = this.Expr();
      if (this.typToken !== CALC_R_BRACKET) {
        this.SendError(5);
      }
      this.GetToken();
    } else {
      temp = this.Expr4();
    }
    return temp;
  }

  Expr4() {
    let temp = null;
    if (this.typToken === CALC_NUMBER) {
      temp = this.CreateNode(atof(this.curToken), null, null);
      this.GetToken();
    } else if (this.typToken === CALC_PI) {
      temp = this.CreateNode(M_PI, null, null);
      this.GetToken();
    } else if (this.typToken === CALC_G) {
      temp = this.CreateNode(F_G, null, null);
      this.GetToken();
    } else if (this.typToken === CALC_L_BRACKET) {
      this.GetToken();
      temp = this.Expr();
      if (this.typToken !== CALC_R_BRACKET) {
        this.SendError(5);
      }
      this.GetToken();
    } else if (this.typToken === CALC_LEET) {
      temp = this.CreateNode(H_LEET, null, null);
      this.GetToken();
    } else {
      this.SendError(5);
    }
    return temp;
  }

  SendError(errNum) {
    if (this.curToken === TERMINATOR) {
      console.log("Пустое выражение");
    } else if (errNum === 2) {
      console.log("Внезапный конец выражения");
    } else if (errNum === 3) {
      console.log("Конец выражения ожидается");
    } else if (errNum === 4) {
      console.log("Пропущеннаи открывающая скобка");
    } else if (errNum === 5) {
      console.log("Пропущенна закрывающая скобка");
    } else {
      console.log("Неизвестная ошибка");
    }
    throw new Error("");
  }

  Compile(_expr) {
    this.pos = 0;
    this.expr = _expr.concat([TERMINATOR]);
    if (this.root !== null) {
      this.root = null;
    }
    this.GetToken();
    if (this.typToken === CALC_END) {
      this.SendError(2);
    }
    this.root = this.Expr();
    if (this.typToken !== CALC_END) {
      this.SendError(3);
    }
    return true;
  }

  GetResult() {
    return this.result;
  }

  Evaluate() {
    this.result = this.CalcTree(this.root);
  }

  CalcTree(tree) {
    if (tree.left === null && tree.right === null) {
      return tree.value;
    } else {
      const op = tree.value;
      switch (op) {
        case OP_PLUS:
          return this.CalcTree(tree.left) + this.CalcTree(tree.right);
        case OP_MINUS:
          return this.CalcTree(tree.left) - this.CalcTree(tree.right);
        case OP_MULTIPLY:
          return this.CalcTree(tree.left) * this.CalcTree(tree.right);
        case OP_DIVIDE:
          return this.CalcTree(tree.left) / this.CalcTree(tree.right);
        case OP_PERCENT:
          return this.CalcTree(tree.left) % this.CalcTree(tree.right);
        case OP_POWER:
          return Math.pow(this.CalcTree(tree.left), this.CalcTree(tree.right));
        case OP_UMINUS:
          return -this.CalcTree(tree.left);
        case OP_SIN:
          return Math.sin(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_COS:
          return Math.cos(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_TG:
          return Math.tan(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_CTG:
          return 1.0 / Math.tan(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_ARCSIN:
          return Math.asin(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_ARCCOS:
          return Math.acos(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_ARCTG:
          return Math.atan(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_ARCCTG:
          return M_PI / 2.0 - Math.atan(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_SH:
          const temp1 = this.CalcTree(tree.left);
          return (Math.exp(temp1) - Math.exp(-temp1)) / 2.0;
        case OP_CH:
          const temp2 = this.CalcTree(tree.left);
          return (Math.exp(temp2) + Math.exp(-temp2)) / 2.0;
        case OP_TH:
          const temp3 = this.CalcTree(tree.left);
          return (
            (Math.exp(temp3) - Math.exp(-temp3)) /
            (Math.exp(temp3) + Math.exp(-temp3))
          );
        case OP_CTH:
          const temp4 = this.CalcTree(tree.left);
          return (
            (Math.exp(temp4) + Math.exp(-temp4)) /
            (Math.exp(temp4) - Math.exp(-temp4))
          );
        case OP_EXP:
          return Math.exp(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_LG:
          return Math.log10(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_LN:
          return Math.log(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_SQRT:
          return Math.sqrt(this.CalcTree(tree.left));
        case OP_IN:
          return 1;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
}

const CALC = new TCALC();

const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

function prompt() {
  readline.question(">> ", (input) => {
    try {
      CALC.Compile(Array.from(input));
      CALC.Evaluate();
      console.log("Ответ:    ", CALC.GetResult());
      console.log("");
    } catch (e) {
      readline.close();
    }
    prompt();
  });
}

prompt();




Нет, не курсовая, таким образом учу JS. Это конечно замечательно что можно сделать вашим образом, но я бы хотел понять, как это сделать в ручную. Тк суть не в результате, а в понимании как оно устроено.

@Dima, когда-то давно, именно я написал этот пример на python) Что могу добавить, бинарное древо, ориентированный граф, рекурсия, абстрактное семантическое древо
